# Json, regex, java. How to replace only one occurency of the substring

Tags: java

Suppose we have string like this

```
 {"className":"first","i":0,"name":null}
```

How to convert it into:

```
 {"className":"second","i":0,"name":null}
```

I have this one:

```
///Initialy className is a className in lower Case (for example "first")
 className = "\"className\":\""+className+"\",";

 string.replaceAll( "\"className\":\".+\"" ,className);
```

But it gives:

```
  {"className":"second",:null}
```

Comment: I think the approach is wrong. You should use some JSON libraries to parse or modify the JSON.

Comment: Actualy I wanted to translate one object to another. Suppose 2 objects have same structure(fields, methods).But only different names. The easiest way I think - replace classname during desserialization?Or may be there is some built in tools to make it via framework? I use jackson

Comment: To do this in regex you can do this: `string.replaceAll( "\"className\":\"[^,]+\"," ,className);`, but I agree that this may not be the most elegant solution to this problem.

Comment: anyway it just kind of puzzles - i am solving some exercises - and this  is one of them. I realize that these kind of tasks can't be encountered in real life. So I still need the answer.

Comment: Mark - that works.Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex has `".+"` in it.  `+` is a "greedy" quantifier, which means that `.+` will match the *largest* possible number of characters.  So the matcher will look all the way to the furthest quote mark it can.  If, instead, you want to match the *smallest* possible number of characters, add `?` after the quantifier, i.e.

```
string.replaceAll( "\"className\":\".+?\"" ,className);
```

In Java this is called a "reluctant" qualifier.  (I've seen it called other names as well.)

I agree with the comments that a regex is not the best approach for this problem.

Comment: Thank you.But, are there any way to make it through built in json tools?

Answer (score 1):

Replace below statement
string.replaceAll( "\"className\":\".+\"" ,className);

with
string.replaceAll( "\"className\":\".+\""+"," ,className);

It gives.

{"className":"second","i":0,"name":null}